# Could a constant function be considered increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Given the definition of an increasing function as a function $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$, where $E$ is nonempty such that $x_1,x_2\in E$ and $x_1<x_2$ imply $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$, then couldn't, for example, $f(x)=-1$ considered increasing? Since the inequality is not a strict inequality.

Comment: Yes.  A constant function is indeed a *monotonically increasing function*.  The stronger statement where $x_1<x_2$ implies $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ is what is called a *strictly increasing function*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (as JMoravitz mentioned) is generally known as a monotone increasing function. That is, a $x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$. So clearly any constant function satisfies this, because $x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$, because $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Note the difference between monotone increasing and strictly increasing. $f$ is said to be strictly increasing if $x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. Of course, the constant function does not satisfy this condition.

Analogous definitions apply for monotone and strictly decreasing functions. Just flip the direction of the inequalities.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is increasing.
However it is not *strictly* increasing.

Note: This is mostly a convention and a matter of definition.

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncreasingFunction.html

Answer (score 0):

Alright let's look at the definitions first:

A function is said to be *Monotonically Increasing* when $x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$

Similarly, a function is said to be *Monotonically Decreasing* when $x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)\ge f(x_2)$

---

So you'd be right to say that the function is *Monotonically Increasing*. In fact you could employ the same reasoning and also argue that the function is *Monotonically Decreasing* since the inequality in both definitions is not strict.

However, I must warn you that this technically correct attribute of the function feels somewhat jarring. Imagine asking your mother if you can get a cat, and after receiving her approval you leave the house and return with a fully grown tiger. Technically, you did get a cat but a painful conversation with your mother still awaits!